# How to create an array of two arrays, and then test it for equality?

Tags: c#, c

```
for (i = 0; i < n0; i++)   
{
    kn[i] = -5;
    ii = i / nn;
    jj = i - nn * ii;
    kk = reg[ii,jj]; // 1st

    if(kk == 1) //2nd
        kn[i] = num++;
}
```

I rework the program from C to C#, and encountered two problems. I already broke my brain trying to solve it. >_< Please tell me what do I pay attention to correct the error.

1st - "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'"

2nd - "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int[]' and 'int'"

Comment: Without the definitions of `kk` and `reg` we can't offer much help, but visibly they are declared with the wrong type.

Comment: @Vache int[] kk; and int reg();

Comment: @user3866037 looks like you have the types backwards, where `kk` should be an `int` and `reg` should be an array.

Comment: Without posting the declared variables there is no way anyone could help you. Also, you should specify which lines you get errors on so people don't have to leave comments for clarification. The more you can put in your OP, the sooner people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggest that you have `reg` or `kn` declared improperly in your C# code.  Instead of being declared as an array, they're declared to be `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'kk' is declared as array so there is a problem. Changing the type of kk from array to int will resolve both your errors

Answer (score 0):

### The two issues you are facing is due to incorrect type declaration.

Please check the type you declared for the 'kk'. It should be like     `int kk;`

- `int kk[];`
  would give the above two errors edit it to `int kk;`
- cannot apply indexing -- because you declared 'kk' as array and didn't index it as kk[i]
- Operator cannot be applied to type int[] -- because you declared kk as array and didnot index it. One solution for both.